# Getting full list of all flights ever made by a person

Tags: air-travel

Is there any kind of service that would allow a person to get a full and complete list of all flight they ever made, regardless of the company and/or country?

Comment: Even airlines have a limited amount of storage space on their servers so they have to delete data after a few years. Hence, even if you contacted each airline you've flown on you still wouldn't be able to go back more than a few years. Though I agree that such a service would be really neat.

Comment: Yeah lots of fun until your psychopath ex starts tracking your flights =).A thirdt party service must access your personal data in each other airline and I doubt a company can easily disclose that information to a third party and even getting your consent/user/password can be a little complicated

Comment: Break into an NSA datacenter, of course.

Comment: @cbw Back in the day, you used to be able to request a [printout of your entire history with United](https://www.travelcodex.com/my-united-airlines-history-mileage-plus-purge-data-print/); after all, how would they know when to send your [3-million-mile lobstergram](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/united-airlines-mileageplus/1330108-2-3-4-million-miler-gift-13.html) unless they kept a comprehensive record? Unfortunately, they seem to have discontinued the service altogether, and claim data prior to 2009 is wholly inaccessible.

Comment: @cbw I know someone who initiated a Subject Access Request on the data held by him by British Airways. He got cardboard boxes full of printouts on his flights going back to the 1980s. This was in the context of being a member of their frequent flyer scheme though.

Comment: What would be the practical purpose, even if that was somehow possible?

Comment: @JonathanReez It's useful if you want to audit your MM progress, but logging flight history is just a hobby for most of us, our version of a wine diary or ballpark map, hence https://openflights.org/, https://www.flightmemory.com/ / https://www.flugstatistik.de/, https://my.flightradar24.com/ , and so on.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately, no. There is no centralized database of all flights someone has taken anywhere in the world.

There may be ways to help reconstruct some of the information:

- Frequent flyer accounts
- Old archived email may contain invoices or confirmations
- Travel booking website accounts
- Governments of countries you've flown to/from may have immigration/advanced passenger information records you can obtain with a records request (e.g. [for the United States](https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia/records))
- Archives in travel organizer applications (e.g. [TripIt](https://www.tripit.com/))

Comment: For business travelers, your corporate travel agency may also have useful records.

Comment: Why do you say "unfortunate"? I would be extremely concerned if this were possible.

Comment: @Kevin Because it's something the OP apparently wants for whatever reason, so for him/her, it's unfortunate that the information isn't available. I will agree it's a good thing for privacy that there's no worldwide travel history database.

Answer (score 6):

As already said, the answer to the question **as written** is no.

However, you can get a heck of a lot of [details of all trips](https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia/records) into or out of USA by air or sea [since 1982](http://apsanlaw.com/law-207.Obtaining-a-Record-of-my-travel-in-and-out-of-the-United-States.html) from the CBP.

What may be disconcerting is [how easily someone else can get it](https://hasbrouck.org/articles/watching.html), and [what kind of information](https://hasbrouck.org/blog/archives/001607.html) they will obtain.

Comment: Also unpleasant is that no matter how detailed and specific your request, you will probably have to push to get what you ask instead of something different.  (More on that in one of the Hasbrouck links.)

Comment: I feel I should disclose that I’ve been trying this method since  LONG before COVID and still have nothing.  COVID is their latest excuse, but they had others in 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no one place or repository where this is all stored.

When I had to recreate all my trips recently for the past 10 years for a security check, the best sources I had were:

- my frequent flyer accounts
- memory
- my bank statements and credit card statements (for buying flights)
- my email. Flight bookings, movements, hotels, etc. All helped a ton.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you have to reconstruct that for just international travel? Or domestic travel too?

Comment: @GregHewgill for an aviation security check, domestic travel only (but I have additional clearances)